# not able to start jboss tried with different ports

Tags: jboss, jboss-eap-7

I have tried changing the ports many times, but it's still not working on AIX.

```
10:23:23,359 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-6) MSC000001: Failed to start service org.wildfly.undertow                                                                     .listener.default: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service org.wildfly.undertow.listener.default: The socket name is alr                                                                     eady in use. /127.0.0.1:8080
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.ListenerService.start(ListenerService.java:179)
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:2032)
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1955)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:808)

10:23:23,434 INFO  [org.jboss.as.ejb3] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYEJB0493: EJB subsystem suspension complete
10:23:23,591 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-3) WFLYJCA0001: Bound data source [java                                                                     :jboss/datasources/ExampleDS]
10:23:23,615 INFO  [org.jboss.as.patching] (MSC service thread 1-4) WFLYPAT0050: JBoss EAP cumulative patch ID is: base, one-off                                                                      patches include: none
10:23:23,646 WARN  [org.jboss.as.domain.management.security] (MSC service thread 1-4) WFLYDM0111: Keystore /usr/u/qaunix/Jboss7/                                                                     standalone/configuration/application.keystore not found, it will be auto generated on first use with a self signed certificate f                                                                     or host localhost
10:23:23,653 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (MSC service thread 1-7) WFLYDS0013: Started FileSystemDeploymentSer                                                                     vice for directory /usr/u/qaunix/Jboss7/standalone/deployments
10:23:23,798 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-3) MSC000001: Failed to start service org.wildfly.manageme                                                                     nt.http.extensible: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service org.wildfly.management.http.extensible: java.net.BindExcepti                                                                     on: The socket name is already in use. /0.0.0.0:9990
        at org.jboss.as.server.mgmt.UndertowHttpManagementService.start(UndertowHttpManagementService.java:340)
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:2032)
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1955)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:808)

10:23:23,832 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-2) MSC000001: Failed to start service org.wildfly.undertow                                                                     .listener.https: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service org.wildfly.undertow.listener.https: The socket name is already                                                                      in use. /127.0.0.1:8443
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.ListenerService.start(ListenerService.java:179)
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:2032)
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1955)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:808)

10:23:23,841 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("add") failed                                                                      - address: ([
    ("core-service" => "management"),
    ("management-interface" => "http-interface")
]) - failure description: {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"org.wildfly.management.http.extensible" => "java.net.BindExceptio                                                                     n: The socket name is already in use. /0.0.0.0:9990"}}
10:23:23,847 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("add") failed                                                                      - address: ([
    ("subsystem" => "undertow"),
    ("server" => "default-server"),
    ("http-listener" => "default")
]) - failure description: {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"org.wildfly.undertow.listener.default" => "The socket name is alr                                                                     eady in use. /127.0.0.1:8080"}}
10:23:23,849 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("add") failed                                                                      - address: ([
    ("subsystem" => "undertow"),
    ("server" => "default-server"),
    ("https-listener" => "https")
]) - failure description: {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"org.wildfly.undertow.listener.https" => "The socket name is alrea                                                                     dy in use. /127.0.0.1:8443"}}
10:23:23,852 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("add") failed                                                                      - address: ([
    ("core-service" => "management"),
    ("management-interface" => "http-interface")
]) - failure description: {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"org.wildfly.management.http.extensible" => "java.net.BindExceptio                                                                     n: The socket name is already in use. /0.0.0.0:9990"}}
10:23:23,878 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYUT0019: Host default-host stopping
10:23:23,889 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-5) WFLYJCA0010: Unbound data source [ja                                                                     va:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS]
10:23:23,893 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYUT0004: Undertow 1.4.18.Final-redhat-2 stopping
10:23:23,909 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-4) WFLYJCA0019: Stopped Driver service with dri                                                                     ver-name = h2
10:23:23,979 FATAL [org.jboss.as.server] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0056: Server boot has failed in an unrecoverable manner                                                                     ; exiting. See previous messages for details.
10:23:23,993 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-8) WFLYSRV0050: JBoss EAP 7.1.0.GA (WildFly Core 3.0.10.Final-redhat-1)                                                                      stopped in 7ms
```

Comment: There errro message says: _The socket name is already in use. /127.0.0.1:8080_ Install and use `lsof` to find out which program uses the port `lsof -n -P -i:8080` Maybe you didn't properly stop the previous run of your program. That's what `kill <pid>; sleep 6; kill -9 <pid>` is good for.

Comment: TY So much.......   it is working below command also :    ps -fu <Username> | grep jboss      after run this command , i killed services using Kill -9 Pid   <Ty so much >

Answer (score 0):

You are getting below error

```
failure description: {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"org.wildfly.undertow.listener.https" => "The socket name is alrea                                                                     dy in use. /127.0.0.1:8443"}}
```

Seems like you have not stopped the previous instance of JBoss or same port is been used by some other applications. Try killing all other processes or open instances of JBoss